# Disabling child control events

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

The child controls of my custom control are obstruction the mouse events in my custom control. I have worked through the accepted answer and the answer at the bottom of this thread...

[exposing-events-of-underlying-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310661/exposing-events-of-underlying-control)

I haven't gotten them to work (the answer at the bottom seemed most straight forward to me). But really I would like to disable the events of them altogether. I have a pictureBox and a label, I don't need to interact with either of the child controls. Is there a way to disable them so they wont interfere with the events of my custom control?

Edit:

I'm using the custom control to gather and process a number of things and make them available as properties. When I click on it, I need to access to the properties. When the event happens at the child control, I don't have access to the propertied of my custom control. The following code is in my form...

```
    public void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var myControl = sender as SubstanceViewer;
        richTextBox1.Text = myControl.substanceInfo;            
    }
```

so I will need to access the properties of the parent control.

Comment: So you do not want the events in the user control at all?

Comment: You might find the accepted answer to this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102982/winforms-equivalent-of-wpfs-ishittestvisible

Comment: No, I just want to disable the events on the child controls, they are interfering with the events on my custom control.

Comment: Then just don't use a PictureBox and Label.  They are very wasteful, it takes just two lines of code in the OnPaint() method to get the same result.  e.Graphics.DrawImage() and TextRenderer.DrawText().  Problem solved.

Comment: Can you give my an example of overriding the OnPaint() method?

Comment: @Hans Passant, this was absolutely the best way to do this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the the events that are normally trapped by the child controls to be handled by the custom control itself, then simply wire up those events at run-time in the constructor of the custom control.

For example if you needed the MouseMove() event of the PictureBox and Label to fire the already wired up event of the UserControl:

```
public partial class SomeUserControl : UserControl
{

    public SomeUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += SomeUserControl_MouseMove;
        this.label1.MouseMove += SomeUserControl_MouseMove;
    }

    private void SomeUserControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

Be aware, though, that since different controls are firing the same handler you'll need to take that into account.  For example, the `e.X` and `e.Y` values in the handler above would be relative to the source control.

*You can also wire these events up at design-time using the IDE itself, but I thought code better illustrated the solution.

Comment: Thanks, that works to catch and process the event of the child control. The problem is I'm using properties of my custom control in my response to the event on my custom control. Can I somehow cast the sender object of the child control as the parent and access the properties of the parent?

Comment: I'm not quite following, can you give a simple example?  I'm sure it can be done somehow...